# t2.micro EC2 instance runs too slow for sometime and then becomes normal

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On a t2.micro EC2 instance I am running a nodejs application which is using mysql DB.

Its a production running server and it was working fine for last one year. Suddenly i have started facing problem. Suddenly at a point of time it becomes too slow and then it becomes normal, even it takes time in loading a static html page.

Some findings to review the EC2 :

[image]

Its an critical issue. Is there any configurations bottlenecks in this instance.

Any help and suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Use datadog or similar monitoring system.

Comment: I think it will take time to configure it. cant i check  from the monitoring tab provided by AWS in the EC2 service dashboard?

Comment: @WilsonHauck please check i have posted some details

Comment: @awadesh  Yes, you have started to post some of the requested information.  Why do you have NO SWAP space?  Until you post other requested information, we can not begin to guess what is wrong.  Start at the top of the list and post additional information one at a time, until done, please.  We now see you have 1GB ram.  Any reason two copies of nodejs are running?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sorry, i don't know much about EC2 configurations. what is No swap space and how to change it, please elaborate. Its default config that i get while spinning this instance. When I am running top command i noticed its giving me the real time stats, sometime there is one copy and other time only one.

Comment: @awadesh Check AWS tutorials for swap space, please.  Continue posting from my list and we will find configuration opportunities.  Will check back in 12 hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174299/discussion-between-awadesh-and-wilson-hauck).

Comment: @WilsonHauck by default AWS instances don't have swap space. Unless you are using an instance type with local SSD storage, then swap space is going to be extremely painfully slow since it will be writing to a volume attached via a network connection. T2.micro instances do not have local storage, hence you would not want to configure swap space on a T2.micro instance.

Comment: @Awadesh unless you post the CPU Credits metrics for your instance out of CloudWatch, we are all just guessing here what the issue might be.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you. I agree we should not configure swap space in this case. I figured it out. when my server was slow, i noticed CPU utilization was 98-99%. I think that is due to lack of CPU credits. Am i right ?

Comment: @Awadesh it could simply be that your application needs a server with a more powerful CPU. Like I said previously, until you actually look at your CPU credits and post them here for us to look at, we are all just guessing at what the issue is.

Comment: @Awadesh also, please don't post duplicate questions, like you did yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146019/node-js-server-is-too-slow

Comment: sure i will remove this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should consider either configuring your instance to use [T2 Unlimited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-unlimited.html) or upgrade your instance to another family (e.g. [C5](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/) or [M5](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/m5/) families).

The instances of the [T2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/) family are burstable, which means that under sustained load, they will become gradually slower as they deplete their CPU credits reserve.

Instances of other families (e.g. C5 or M5) will not slow down under sustained load like T2 instances do.

Comment: Could you please check my edited question, is there any problem with the CPU usage. I wanna know when i can consider my CPU is not running properly

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem with t2.micro and neither CPU credits, nor Burst Balance are nowhere near depleted, in fact didn't decrease at all. Restarting the instance solves the problem every time, so it's not a question of credits.